# Ajaxify comment posting and replies in Ruby on Rails 4?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm fairly new to Ruby on rails or coding in general. I've been following  [this tutorial](http://dustinfisher.com/acts-as-commentable-with-threading-gem/) to build a commenting system on my Ruby on rails web app using acts-as-commentable-with-threading-gem.

I'm trying to ajaxify "Post" and "Reply" actions so that the new comments get appended to the page without having to reload. But it results in the following error:

```
"ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial comments/_comment with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}."
```

I've been trying to figure this out but no luck so far.
I've modified the "def create" part of the comments controller as follows:

```
def create
  commentable = commentable_type.constantize.find(commentable_id)
  @comment = Comment.build_from(commentable, current_user.id, body)
  @comments = Comment.where(commentable_id: commentable_id)

  respond_to do |format|
   if @comment.save
     make_child_comment
     format.html { redirect_to(:back) }
     format.js
   else
     format.html { render :action => "new" }
     format.js
   end
  end
end
```

and created a views/comments/create.js.erb file with the following code:

```
$('.comments-container').prepend("<%= j render @comments %>");
```

and of course modified the form actions in form as well as reply templates to respond to asynchronous requests as:

_reply.html.erb line:7

```
<%= form_for @new_comment, remote: true do |f| %>
```

_form.html.erb line:1

```
<%= form_for @new_comment, remote: true do |f| %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're new, I'll give you some info, although I've not used `acts-as-commentable-with-threading` before.

---

> ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing partial comments/_comment

The error basically means you don't have the `app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb` [partial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials).

The problem is here:

```
<%= j render @comments %>
```

--

As per the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-collections):

> When a partial is called with a pluralized collection, then the individual instances of the partial have access to the member of the collection being rendered via a variable named after the partial. In this case, the partial is `_product`, and within the `_product` partial, you can refer to `product` to get the instance that is being rendered.

This means that if you're calling `render @comments`, Rails is going to look up the `_comment.html.erb` partial. Because it cannot find it, your error appears.

The fix is to move your comment code into a partial, and use that to populate your `comments`:

```
#app/views/comments/show.html.erb
<%= render @comment %>

#app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
<%= comment.title %> #-> put your comment code here
```

This should fix your error.

Comment: @Rick Peck
Thanks Mr peck, that worked like a charm. Although now I'm running into a different error. The comments on the app are posted but not visible until a page refresh.

Here's the error that I get:

ArgumentError - First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty:
  actionview (4.2.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:432:in `form_for'
  app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:20:in `block in _app_views_comments__comment_html_erb___265496053_64199412'
  C:0:in `each'
  app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_comments__comment_html_erb___265496053_64199412'